# How to get GridViewItem from its child element?

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8

Suppose I have a code in XAML like this:

```
<GridView>
  <GridView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Content="{Binding test}" Click="ButtonClick" />
</DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Then how can I get which **GridViewItem** was selected? Because, normally what is done is to add the *ItemClick functionality to the GridView itself*, but in this case I am doing something customized and need to get the SelectedItem starting from the Button.

I tried code something like this:

```
void ButtonClick (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var g = (GridViewItem)((Button)sender).Parent;
}
```

But it does not work (returns null). Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Whether the XAML code is correct? I was not able to find the Property ItemTemplate for GridView http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview%28v=vs.100%29

Comment: Yes it is correct. I am getting null from g now, but if I do using <GridViewItem>, I can get the GridViewItem object.

Comment: Look at this http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html

Answer (score 1):

Sure! Here's the code that I use when the ad control fails to load an ad (like when the machine is offline). In that case I remove it form the gridview. To do that I have to locate the ad's parent gridviewitem and remove the whole thing. I do it like this:

```
private void AdControl_ErrorOccurred_1(object sender, Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI.AdErrorEventArgs e)
{
    var _Item = sender as DependencyObject;
    while (!(_Item is GridViewItem))
        _Item = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(_Item);
    HubGrid.Items.Remove(_Item);
}
```